# Unable to get workflow id in oozie workflow EL

Tags: hadoop, el, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I am trying to get the workflow ID in the oozie workflow EL as,

`${wf:id()}`

Upon execution, oozie complains that no function is mapped to the same. Same is happening with `wf:username()`

However I am able to get `wf:actionData`.

Using oozie-3.3.2-cdh4.5.0 with the sample workflow as :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.2" name="NAME:${wf:id()}">
  <start to="end"/>
  <end name = "end">
</workflow-app>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Provide your oozie version you are using and your workflow also?

Comment: Updated with the required information.